# Parsing a kind of csv file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csv

I have a kind of csv file, with some extra parameters. I don't want to write my own parser since I know there are alot of good ones out there. The problem is that I'm unsurtan if there is any parser that could handle my scenario. 
My csv file looks like this:

[image: The CSV file]

I would like to first read the second lines below # ADM so in this case 3 lines. And the I would like to read the second line after # Prov.

Is there any good parser or reader that I could use that would help me with this, and how would I write to handle my scenario?

The extension of my file is not .csv either, it's .lab , but I guess thats not going to be a problem ?

Comment: What would be the benefit from reading the second lines below ... ?

Comment: What language? You should just write your own parser. It will be quick and easy. You can probably get it done by the time you get an answer and learn any tools recommended here.

Comment: If this is on a Linux/UNIX system you might be able to use a tool like sed or awk to do most or all of the work.

Comment: Sorry, missed the language, it's .net 4, with c#.

Comment: I think it's quite easy to write your own parser. Parser libs on market are used to parse common cases (which are a lot), but you only need for a specific case. So your own parser will be much faster, and you can learn when writing parser as well :)

Comment: This would be a nice case to use split(#) and after that another set of splits ;). That if the file is not long to fill up all the memory..

Comment: Could anybody point me in the right direction. So I read it and have a big string in memory, than I will need to split this on the # tag. Keep it in a list, or dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fore*, I didn't see a spefic language for the task, and read too late about `c#`. Here is a `perl` solution, but is well commented, so I hope it can be useful and easy to translate to other languages.

Assuming a test file (`infile`) like:

```
1
2
3
4
5

#Adm
6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

#Prov                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

#Adm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#Prov                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
12                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#Adm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
14                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

#Prov                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
16                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
17
```

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Assign empty value to read file by paragraphs.
$/ = qq[];

## Arrays to save second row of its section.
my (@adm, @prov);

## Regex to match beginning of section.
my $regex = qr/(?:#(?|(Adm)|(Prov)))/;

## Read file.
while ( <> ) { 

    ## Remove last '\n'.
    chomp;

    ## If matches the section and it has at least two lines...
    if ( m/\A${regex}/ and tr/\n/\n/ == 2 ) { 

        ## Group the section name ($1) and its second line ($2).
        if ( m/\A${regex}.*\n^(.*)\Z/ms ) { 

            ## Save line in an array depending of section's value.
            if ( $1 eq q[Adm] ) { 
                push @adm, $2; 
            }   
            elsif ( $1 eq q[Prov] ) { 
                push @prov, $2; 
            }   
        }   
    }   
}

## Print first lines of 'Adm' section and later lines of 'Prov' section.
for ( ( @adm, @prov ) ) { 
    printf qq[%s\n], $_; 
}

exit 0;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

With following output:

```
7
11
15
9
13
17
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ended up writing my own parser, and used some of this code.